# Flat polygon feature to serve floors to time bins on Z axis of ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, 3d-analyst, arcscene

How can I create square polygons with different z-values to create the horizontal panes shown in the image from ArcScene?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using ArcScene so I have focussed this question on ArcGIS for Desktop. You can always ask about ArcGIS Pro in a separate question if this one does not provide a solution.